# объединение запросов БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, postgresql

Подскажите как объединить два запроса в один, в нете подходящей инфы не нашел

```
select "Text",
case
when "UsersIDSender" = 3
then "UsersIDRecipient"
else "UsersIDSender"
end
as Sender
from posts
where "UsersIDSender" = 3 or "UsersIDRecipient" = 3
```

и

```
select
case
when "UsersIDSender" = 3 
then 'outgoing'
else 'incoming'
end
as x
from posts
```

Чтобы при выполнении вывело 3 колонки (Text, Sender, x).
Спасибо!

Comment: Я конечно всё понимаю...

Comment: причем тут C#? Я так понимаю, вы SQL запрос не можете нужны написать?

Comment: подключаюсь и выполняю запрос в с#, но тут без разницы в каком формате, после перенесу SQL запрос в программу

Comment: Формулируйте задачу, а не свои попытки её решить. *объединить два запроса в один* - забыть про два запроса и написать один с нуля.